Upgrade to 24.4 failing
The firmware package is not installing.
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive '/var/cache/apt/archives/linux-firmware_20240318.git3b128b60-0ubuntu2.4_amd64.deb' (size=483854410)
member 'data.tar': zstd error: Data corruption detected

I have tried forcing a re-install and re-downloading the package and the error still occurs. How do I fix this.
Full command output below:
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-firmware_20240318.git3b128b60-0ubuntu2.4_amd64.deb
(Reading database ... 312180 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-firmware_20240318.git3b128b60-0ubuntu2.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-firmware (20240318.git3b128b60-0ubuntu2.4) over (20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.34) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive '/var/cache/apt/archives/linux-firmware_20240318.git3b128b60-0ubuntu2.4_amd64.deb' (size=483854410) member 'data.tar': zstd error: Data corruption detected
dpkg-deb: error: <decompress> subprocess returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-firmware_20240318.git3b128b60-0ubuntu2.4_amd64.deb (--install):
 cannot copy extracted data for './lib/firmware/mrvl/pcieuart8997_combo_v4.bin.zst' to '/lib/firmware/mrvl/pcieuart8997_combo_v4.bin.zst.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-45-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-122-generic
dracut-install: could not get modinfo from 'cicada': Exec format error
dracut-install: could not get modinfo from 'cortina': Exec format error
dracut-install: could not get modinfo from 'dp83822': Exec format error
dracut-install: could not get modinfo from 'dp83867': Exec format error
dracut-install: could not get modinfo from 'dp83848': Exec format error
dracut-install: could not get modinfo from 'dp83640': Exec format error
dracut-install: could not get modinfo from 'bcm54140': Exec format error
dracut-install: could not get modinfo from 'bcm7xxx': Exec format error
dracut-install: could not get modinfo from 'davicom': Exec format error
dracut-install: could not get modinfo from 'broadcom': Exec format error
dracut-install: could not get modinfo from 'et1011c': Exec format error
dracut-install: could not get modinfo from 'bcm87xx': Exec format error
depmod: ERROR: failed to load symbols from /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_oobXcr/lib/modules/5.15.0-122-generic/kernel/drivers/net/phy/bcm54140.ko: Exec format error
depmod: ERROR: failed to load symbols from /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_oobXcr/lib/modules/5.15.0-122-generic/kernel/drivers/net/phy/bcm7xxx.ko: Exec format error
depmod: ERROR: failed to load symbols from /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_oobXcr/lib/modules/5.15.0-122-generic/kernel/drivers/net/phy/bcm87xx.ko: Exec format error
depmod: ERROR: failed to load symbols from /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_oobXcr/lib/modules/5.15.0-122-generic/kernel/drivers/net/phy/broadcom.ko: Exec format error
depmod: ERROR: failed to load symbols from /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_oobXcr/lib/modules/5.15.0-122-generic/kernel/drivers/net/phy/cicada.ko: Exec format error
depmod: ERROR: failed to load symbols from /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_oobXcr/lib/modules/5.15.0-122-generic/kernel/drivers/net/phy/cortina.ko: Exec format error
depmod: ERROR: failed to load symbols from /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_oobXcr/lib/modules/5.15.0-122-generic/kernel/drivers/net/phy/davicom.ko: Exec format error
depmod: ERROR: failed to load symbols from /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_oobXcr/lib/modules/5.15.0-122-generic/kernel/drivers/net/phy/dp83640.ko: Exec format error
depmod: ERROR: failed to load symbols from /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_oobXcr/lib/modules/5.15.0-122-generic/kernel/drivers/net/phy/dp83822.ko: Exec format error
depmod: ERROR: failed to load symbols from /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_oobXcr/lib/modules/5.15.0-122-generic/kernel/drivers/net/phy/dp83848.ko: Exec format error
depmod: ERROR: failed to load symbols from /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_oobXcr/lib/modules/5.15.0-122-generic/kernel/drivers/net/phy/dp83867.ko: Exec format error
depmod: ERROR: failed to load symbols from /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_oobXcr/lib/modules/5.15.0-122-generic/kernel/drivers/net/phy/et1011c.ko: Exec format error
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-112-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-97-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-firmware_20240318.git3b128b60-0ubuntu2.4_amd64.deb


There might be a problem on the server side (i.e. from where you downloaded the package). Perhaps retry after a while?

I did try switching from UK server to the Main server - didn't help :-(

Of course those servers might be the same, so trying a USA mirror.

Usually, when you have the Exec format error, the tools used to build the modules aren't compatible with the running kernel.
Please ensure the installed versions and architecture are appropriate for the machine and kernel running. The best way to achieve this would be to boot with a USB disk, preferably with the same version you are moving to, remove the installed firmware package, and reinstall using the package manager.
The steps to achieve this are:

Boot from the USB disk. Once you hit the shell, identify your disks using lsblk

Create a folder to mount the partition with mkdir -p /mnt/root

Now mount some filesystems into the new root folder:


mount /dev/sdXY /mnt/root
mount --bind /dev /mnt/root/dev
mount --bind /proc /mnt/root/proc
mount --bind /sys /mnt/root/sys


Now chroot into the mount filesystem and configure DNS resolution:

chroot /mnt/root /bin/bash
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" >> /etc/resolv.conf

It is possible to verify if this is working with:
ping -c 2 google.com

The following steps are to remove the firmware package, ensure the sources.list points to the correct version, update the cache, upgrade any pending packages, and install the proper firmware package.

Find the installed firmware package and remove it:

dpkg -l '*linux-firmware*'
# check if there are different versions and remove the one you forced to install
apt remove --purge linux-firmware-xxxxx


Check the files in /etc/apt/sources.list and /etc/apt/sources.list.d and see if they point to the noble version. Sometimes, when the upgrade fails, these files are reverted to the previous version.

Run the update and upgrade to ensure everything is up-to-date.


apt update
apt upgrade -y


Reinstall the firmware package

apt install linux-firmware


Umount the filesystems

umount /mnt/root/sys
umount /mnt/root/proc
umount /mnt/root/dev
umount /mnt/root


Reboot and check if it is working.


OP did not mention changing architecture.

No, he didn't. Neither did I say the error is architecture-related. The error is usually related to modules being built for a different kernel version than the one running.

Created a live boot USB stick, rebooted, mounted the failing installation and removed the linux-firmware .deb file that was giving the errors.

Created a live boot USB stick, rebooted, mounted the failing installation and removed the linux-firmware .deb file that was giving the errors.
apt-upgrade then fails:
E: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_20240318.git3b128b60-0ubuntu2.4_amd64.deb  Could not resolve 'gb.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Aborting install.

@GilesDavidson I added to the answer above, but you may fix the name resolution with echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > /etc/resolv.conf, inside the chroot.

Downloaded the linux firmware package linux-firmware_20240318.git3b128b60-0ubuntu2.4_amd64.deb from http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/
and installed it.Problem resolved

Thanks to replies to the original question - one lives and learns!
